# How do I subscribe to questions that I have a good chance of answering?

Tags: support, questions

I'm trying to increase my reputation score, but I only encounter questions that others ask when I'm searching for similar subjects.  Obviously, if I knew the answer I wouldn't be searching for one.  So, if I want to increase my reputation I need to get notified of questions asked in the subjects I know about.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious way, mouse over a tag and click on **subscribe** or **RSS** --

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/tag-favorites-and-tag-subscriptions/

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/tag-favorites-subscribe2.png))</sub>

Answer (score 6):

You can subscribe to different tags (look up in the page). That's a good start.

BTW, I saw it as one of the "recent questions"

Comment: Update: do you see the number next to your question? Those are upvotes also. Asking good questions is another way to increase the rep :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use Chrome (and there's no doubt similar options for other browser), then New Q! is a great extension which notifies you of new questions based on tags...

[New Q! - Google Chrome Extension notifies you of new questions of interest and inbox messages (now with API v2.0!)](https://stackapps.com/questions/587/new-q-google-chrome-extension-notifies-you-of-new-questions-of-interest)

Answer (score -4):

Use your "Favourites" (the star under the vote panel).