# How can I find questions that I can answer with my skillset?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I really like helping people and help many people on Firefox addon development sites. but there its easy, you go to a certain section of the forum and that's where all the relevant stuff to my skill set/expertise is. With stackoverflow there's so much. I want to help and get help, how can I get notified of questions that fall in my expertise?

Comment: thanks arthur but i dont understand

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85570/147191.

Answer (score 3):

On Stack Overflow, all questions have tags that specify what the question is about. For example, there is a [firefox-addon](/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) tag.

To make it easier to find questions relating to Firefox addons, you can add the tag to your favorites using the Favorite Tags section at the top right of the [Stack Overflow homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/). This will make questions with the [firefox-addon](/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) tag be highlighted in yellow in question lists throughout the website.

If you'd like to be emailed when new questions with a specific tag are posted, you can go to the [network-wide filters page](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) and create a filter and set it to email you about new questions. Be aware that it will not email you instantly. It may take a few hours before you are notified that a new question that matches your filter.